# SyntaxError: invalid Syntax using the .tolist() function in python while assigning values to columns

Tags: python, random-forest

I have a column in my csv file called 'sport' containing different sport names. I'm trying to assign them a popularity score. But when I type in the following (I'm using Python), I get the proceeding error.

```
Sports_Popularity_Score = [9 if sport=='football' else 7 if sport=='hockey'
else 6 if sport=='basketball' else 5 if sport=='baseball' else 4 if sport=='tennis' else 3 if sport=='gymnastics' else 2 if sport=='olympics' else 1 for sport df['sport'].tolist()]
```

Error message:
File "sport_popularity.py", line 74

```
Sports_Popularity_Score = [9 if sport=='football' else 7 if sport=='hockey'
else 6 if sport=='basketball' else 5 if sport=='baseball' else 4 if sport=='tennis' else 3 if sport=='gymnastics' else 2 if sport=='olympics' else 1 for sport df['sport'].tolist()]

^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there something wrong with the way I formatted my df section? The name of the column is sport and the value in each cell is a string: football, hockey, etc. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't use a nested ternary like that.

Comment: what are you doing with the values, I imagine you are using pandas so there is most likely a much better way to do what you want

Comment: Mystery upvoter: In what way is this question "useful and clear"? How does it demonstrate research effort? In what sense will it be useful to future visitors of the site?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm eventually going to make a matrix of 8 different features. Sports_Popularity_Score would be one of the features on the feature_list. I have imported pandas. But I didn't know there was a better way.
The feature_list is going to consist of the variable I assigned (e.g. Sports_Popularity_Score) rather than the original column name (unless I'm wrong on the syntax as well).

e.g. (assuming I'm not wrong on this syntax)

feature_list = [Sports_Popularity_Score, Sports_Physical_Difficulty, Cost_to_play]

Comment: just `dict(zip(range(1 ,len(feature_list)+1),feature_list ))` and use that instead of the multiple if/else,  what will be the columns and the rows of your df?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham. are you free for me to screenshare my whole code set somehow? I'm not sure how to answer your question regarding what will be the rows of my df because they depend on the values under each column. Ultimately, the program is going to be pumping out a recommendation.

Comment: @vuxxx036, you can add it to pastebin, might not get to it tonight but will have a look in the a.m, add a few comments so I know what it is you are trying to do

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks! I need to finish up defining my features. But I'll get it out by tonight.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham.I don't know how to add it to pastebin so that you can see it.But here's the code at GitHub: github.com/nicholasvu/Capstone_Project/blob/master/… I think I'm going to need to explain it to you in depth because it's a recommendation engine telling you if you should override/cancel/view a dose alert that fires to a provider. Some of the vocabulary may not make sense (which is why I utilized sports as an example case so it was easier to understand before I applied the solution to my specific code). Also, I'll prob need to explain the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing "in"

Also, this is the kind of thing you should do with a dict:

```
popularities = {'football': 9, 'hockey': 7, <etc...>}
sports_popularity_score = [popularities[sport] for sport in df['sport'].tolist()]
```

Comment: Instead of `popularities[sport]`, I would do `popularities.get(sport, 1)`. Note the `else` in the original, implying that a given `sport` may not be in the dictionary, and any sport not in the list has a default popularity of 1.

Comment: Thanks. that solved it. And I'll use your dict style next time.

Comment: @vuxxx036 - Note that this answer will produce an error if you try to pass a sport that's not in the dictionary, instead of simply assigning it a popularity of 1. My above comment fixes that.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 got it. thanks for simplifying it into something for readable!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `in`:

```
for sport in df['sport'].tolist()
           ^
```

I would also recommend a different approach, the error was hard to spot as the code is not very readable.

Comment: thanks. that solved it. I'll post code more clearly next time.

Comment: @vuxxx036, no worries, takes a while to get used to the formatting